# Data structure to mock a file directory

Tags: java

I have a requirement where I have to parse a file directory and its sub directories and files within them. Further I have to do some statistics on the file sizes within these directories and visualize the results on two screens:

1) Folder tree with directories, sub-directories and files **(size > 50 mb)**

2) Folder tree with directories, sub-directories and files **(size < 50 mb)**

Printing the results right away by parsing the file structure is easy but I can't think of any data structure where I can remember the directory and sub directories and files within it.

This is something I have already implemented for parsing the directory:

```
    public void listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories(String directoryName) {
    File directory = new File(directoryName);
    //get all the files from a directory
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
    for (File file : fList) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath() + "    " + file.length() / 1024);
            countWords(file.getAbsolutePath());
            findRepeatedWords(file.getAbsolutePath());
        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```

The place I have written Sysout statment, I want to use a data structure where I can store directory and its sub directories and files and files within those sub directories.
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: You mean something like a ..... [tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)?

Comment: Have you considered to use th JDK abstractions like `FileSystem`, `File`, `Path`, etc.directly?

Comment: @tom Yes, exactly. But the there would be two views filtered based on some criteria.

Comment: @AndreasMueller I have updated my question. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Any Tree like data structure is suited for your problem. That may be a `LinkedList`, a `TreeMap`, or `TreeNode`s like the Swing TreeNodes.

Starting with *Java 7* you can use  the [FileVisitor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html) to build and filter your internal structure / view model.

In the  following simple example a `FileVisitor` is used to build a view model a view model of some directory. The `FilePathNode` is an Adaptor for the `java.nio.file.Path` object. I've put in some comments where a you may add the filter logic. The example only shows just one screen for the second screen / view one would a second `JTree` element with a second view model.

```
package filetreeexamle;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.MutableTreeNode;


public class FileTreeSwingUIExample {


    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private static class FilePathNode extends DefaultMutableTreeNode {

        // store additional stuff like used diskspace (for directories and files)


        public FilePathNode(Path path) {
            super(path);
        }

        @Override
        public void add(MutableTreeNode newChild) {
            if (((Path)getUserObject()).toFile().isFile()) 
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't add a child node to a file.");
            super.add(newChild);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLeaf() {
            return ((Path)getUserObject()).toFile().isFile();
        }   

    }   

    private static class TreeViewControllerDelegate {
        private JTree treeView;

        private static class FileTreeBuilder implements FileVisitor<Path> {

            // node where the builder starts 
            // contains the whole subtree after processing the whole tree
            FilePathNode rootNode;

            // temporary reference to the directory currently processed.
            private FilePathNode currentDir;                

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {

                currentDir = new FilePathNode(dir);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                FilePathNode fileNode = new FilePathNode(file);
                // here you can add filter conditions for files
                // also you may update the consumed disk space of the parent directory
                currentDir.add(fileNode);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException {
                if (exc != null) throw exc;
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
                if (exc != null) throw exc;

                // here you can filter directories like directories
                // which use more than n MB of diskspce.

                if (rootNode == null) {
                    rootNode = currentDir;
                } else {
                    rootNode.add(currentDir);
                }
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }


        }

        public TreeViewControllerDelegate(JTree treeView) {
            this.treeView = treeView;
        }

        public void load(Path path) {           

            FileTreeBuilder builder = new FileTreeBuilder();
            try {
                Files.walkFileTree(path, builder);
                treeView.setModel(new DefaultTreeModel(builder.rootNode) );
                treeView.repaint();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Failed to load file strucutre",
                        "Error",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String ... args) {


        JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame("Sample File Tree View");
        JTree fileTree = new JTree();

        TreeViewControllerDelegate controller = new TreeViewControllerDelegate(fileTree);
        controller.load(Paths.get("."));

        mainWindow.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainWindow.add(fileTree, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainWindow.setSize(200, 300);
        mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```